# Kohana (or straight PHP) OAuth2 implementation

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, kohana

Does anyone have a very clear step-by-step guide for implementing OAuth2 (preferably in Kohana 3.2, but I'll take whatever I can get)?

I would like it to include the tables I need to create, etc.  (Hard to implement something without knowing the table structure.)

UPDATE:

I completely forgot to mention that I'm looking for a Provider implementation!  Thanks! (and sorry).

Answer (score 2):

You can try to analyze [oauth2-php](http://code.google.com/p/oauth2-php/)

Comment: Yeah, it seems like, thus far, that has been about my best option...  (and it's a pretty decent option)...  was just hoping for a step-by-step.  Maybe I'll have to do it myself and give back to the community :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like, after hours of research, this (http://edin.no-ip.com/comment/348) is about the closest I could get.  It takes @mrok's suggestion a step further.  (PS - thanks, @mrok)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps: https://github.com/kohana-world (look into https://github.com/kohana-world/kw-accounts and https://github.com/kohana-world/kw-auth modules). Unfortunately, currently we have no time for development :(

PS. Also I've wrote an article about OAuth2 in Kohana, you can try to translate it from russian: http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=ru&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http://brotkin.ru/2011/05/24/oauth-v2/

Comment: Man!  Where were you two days ago?!  :)  Only stinky thing with that translation is that it doesn't translate the images, but I think after all my research I have an idea of what they say, anyway.

Thank you!  for this!

Comment: One thing it doesn't have, though, is the tables to implement.  Also, I did forget to mention (but I'm editing my post to reflect it), that I'm looking for an implementation of a Provider.  However, your article does help to understand things a little bit more, so thank you.